# How many collectibles are there, and in what chapters can I find them?

Tags: quantum-conundrum

*Quantum Conundrum* released today, and I'm thoroughly enjoying my time solving these puzzles, and hunting for collectibles.

Being a completionist, I hate the idea of missing a collectible (especially if there is an achievement involved).

**Just how many are there? If possible, where can I find them?**

<sup>Note: I am not asking for detailed information on each collectible. A simple "This chapter has this many" or something of that sort will suffice. In the event the total number of collectibles is too high, I will be removing that part from the question.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Level Select/Stats screen, there are 24 collectables total.

[image: Overall collectables]

You can also view the number of collectables in each chapter from the level-select screen, including how many you have *(or don't have)*.

[image: collectables in first chapter]

If you are missing a collectable for a level, it will be grayed out

[image: missing collectable]

---

The specific levels they are in:

**Blue Wing** (8 total):

- Robot things

  - Air Raising Scheme
  - Stairway to Fluffy
  - Is this the real life, is this just fan-tasy?
  - Springing to New Heights
  - Mind the Gap
  - End of the Beginning
- Blueprints:

  - A Fluffy Journey of Discovery
  - Around the World

**Yellow Wing** (8 total):

- Robot things

  - Ticket to Ride
  - It's Slow Throwing from Here on Out
  - Is it Safe to Ride?
  - The Odds Are Stacked Against You
  - A Boost of Confidence
  - Catch and Release
  - The Path to Higher Learning
- Blueprints

  - What Goes Around...

**Red Wing** (6 total):

- Robot things

  - The Safe-est Way to Travel
  - Going Up?
  - A Course of Matter
  - Flipping Out
  - Choose Wisely
- Blueprints

  - Nothin' but Vat

There is also a robot-thing in the **Uber IDS** level and one in the **Research and Development Lab** *(which requires anti-gravity and slow-time to get to)*.

Comment: If what I briefly saw last night is accurate, the three greyed out icons in the top-left (robot thing, blueprint, heart) of your screenshot can indicate what levels have what items. If you scroll through the levels (not chapters) the icons will only show up against levels that *have* a robot thing, blurprint or ike to find, and the icon will light up if you've found it. Someone who can access the game now (I'm at work) would have to double check this.

Comment: @DMA57361: Not sure, I haven't missed any collectables yet :) But, I think the heart means *"beat the level without dying,"* not *"found ike."*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft While doing my playthrough, I noticed the "Overall" collectible count being 1 higher than the total of all of the Wings/final area of the game. I'd be interested to know if you encountered a similar issue.

Comment: Turns out the heart icon is for passing the level(s) end to end without dying (so the 'levels without deaths' stat), the other two icons did what I though they did. :)

Comment: @DMA57361: Yep, you're right, if a collectable is missed it shows up as grayed out in the level select screen.  Interestingly enough, I missed that collectable because you were supposed to find and use all four battery types in that level, but I beat it after getting the first one :)

Comment: @Fluttershy: The last one is in the research and development lab.